# I need timeseries function and its methods example in Palantir foundry fusion?

Tags: palantir-foundry

i know there are some functions in foundry fusion we can use like action or validate.
i also can see that there is mention about timeseries function in fusion documentation but i'm not able to use it as there is no sufficient documentation to support and also ts function itself when written is giving error.
any idea on this?
thanks in advance.

Tried functions like action and validate in fusion and successfully created samples but not able to do same with time series functions!